# How to keep "*/" in regular expression from being interpreted as block comment?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm working on a bookmarklet which is using the [replaceText](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-replacetext-plugin/) plugin to wrap all words (and extraneous spaces/punctuation) on a page in span tags.  That plugin traverses all the text nodes on a page and allows me to call a function to manipulate the contents of each one without breaking any other HTML formatting on the page.  (None of this is the problem, I'm pretty sure, but I felt like the context might be useful).  My call of the function looks like this, for your reference:

```
$("body *").replaceText(/\S+\s*/g, spanWrap);
```

The problem is that the best regular expression I've found for separating these words for my purposes -- `/\S+\s*/g` -- contains the characters for the end of a block comment ("*/").  If I add the opening of a block comment a few lines before it in the .js file in Notepad++, I can see that the syntax highlighter is reading it as that.

When I run my bookmarklet, most sites seem to have no problem with this issue and the bookmarklet works as intended.  However, some sites, for reasons I can't predict, throw up an "`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`" error and the bookmarklet breaks/stops running.  If I change the regular expression I'm using in the `replaceText` function to one I had been using in an earlier version of the bookmarklet -- `/\b(\S+?)\b/g` -- while changing absolutely nothing else in the bookmarklet, these sites stop giving the error and the bookmarklet works just fine, so I have to believe that it's the presence of the block comment closure that's causing it.

For the purposes of what I'm trying to do with the bookmarklet, though, the expression with that comment closure in it --`/\S+\s*/g`-- works much, much better than the other one, which doesn't catch punctuation and white space.  However, I'd also really like it if my bookmarklet didn't break on certain sites.

So, is there either a way to fix the regular expression that I have so that it's not being read as a comment or can you suggest one that can do the same job maybe with a different syntax or something?  (If it's not obvious from my question, I have the barest understanding of how regular expressions work and have gotten the ones I'm using in this example by copying them from other Stack Overflow questions/answers)

Comment: I doubt that any JavaScript engine interprets this sequence as the end of a comment. That would be really, really strange.

Comment: @FelixKling — I'd be surprised if any did not: http://jsbin.com/ocomuy/1/

Comment: @Quentin: Ok, if it is inside of one, sure. But not by itself. **edit:** Apparently I did not read the question properly. Still, since this is a bookmarklet I doubt the error has anything to do with potential block comments.

Comment: Tell us what the regex is supposed to do, if you want us to suggest alternatives.

Comment: What stops this from inserting spans inside script tags on the page? that could easily break pages with inline scripts

Comment: @Some1.Kill.The.DJ spanWrap is the function I'm calling to put the spans around the strings isolated by the regular expression.  Very simple, here it is: `   function spanWrap( str ){
    spanCounter = spanCounter + 1;
    return "<span id='word" + spanCounter + "'>" + str + "<\/span>";
   };`

Comment: @ChaseMedallion : see plugin link in post

Comment: @marsze - the regex is supposed to separate out each word (including surrounding/adjacent/loose punctuation and whitespace) so that I can call a function to wrap each of those words in a span with a unique ID. the problem with the second regex i listed in my question is that it doesn't catch some of the punctuation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the long version:

```
var regex = new RegExp("\\S+\\s*", "g");
$("body *").replaceText(regex, spanWrap);
```

*(EDIT: Escaped the backslashes in the string)*

Comment: This methodology seems really smart and I kind of smacked myself in the forehead when I saw it, but I tried this out and while it runs on the pages which the short version breaks, it doesn't function the same way (i.e. the short version is wrapping word (including punctuation and surrounding whitespace) in span tags, whereas this is only doing that to a few of the words)

Comment: here is a slightly more lucid version of the above comment: This methodology seems really smart and I kind of smacked myself in the forehead when I saw it, but I tried this out and while it runs on the pages which the short version breaks, it doesn't function the same way (i.e. the short version is triggering my function to wrap every word (including punctuation and surrounding whitespace) in span tags, whereas this is only doing that to a few of the words on the page and leaving most untouched)

Comment: @JJohnson : This seems odd. I'll try to figure out why this happens (it shouldn't...). In the meanwhile, you can use this page for testing regexes: http://regexpal.com/

Comment: @JJohnson : See the edit in my answer, you have to escape the backslashes in the string - but I guess you did that, otherwise it wouldn't work at all. Also: did you remember to add the **"g"** as second parameter in the **RegExp**-contructor? By the behavior you described it seems like you missed that.

Comment: Yep, I figured out the escaping through some reading and trial and error myself, but wouldn't have gotten there without your first attempt.  It turned out that what was causing the behavior I asked the question about was (of course) something else, but I'm still glad to have found a new/better way to do this and learned a little more about regex.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

> So, is there either a way to fix the regular expression that I have so that it's not being read as a comment

I can't think of anything sane. (You could get the effect by using the `RegExp` constructor and breaking the regex up into two strings and then concatenating them back together for the regex. I wouldn't call that sane though.)

I'd use a series of line comments `//` instead of a block comment.